# Running JQuery in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

My html file:

```
<html><body>example !</body></html>
```

My manifest.json

```
    {
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Test",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","file://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["myscript.js","jquery-1.10.2.min.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

myscript.js file:

```
/*var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
    divtest.id = "divTest";
    document.body.appendChild(divtest);*/

$("body").append("Test");
```

The JS commented-out code works. The JQuery on the other hand does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to run your script before jQuery is initialized, so by the time you run `$("body")` - `$` is not "jQuery" yet. You need to load jQuery first:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Test",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","file://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```